# Import the perforce depot to linux development environment

Tags: perforce

I need to import the perforce depot workspace into linux development Environment.

I am getting error as p4passwd unset on p4 sync and login. Can anyone please explain this?

Comment: I suspect there are more questions here than apparent, but to start, try "p4 login".

Comment: This isn't really a programming question at all. You should start by reading the Perforce documentation, such as the "getting started" guide. Here's a good place to start: https://www.perforce.com/manuals/cmdref/Content/CmdRef/introduction.help.html

Answer (score 1):

Run:

```
p4 set P4USER=your_user_name
p4 set P4CLIENT=your_client_name
```

where `your_user_name` is your actual Perforce username and `your_client_name` is the unique name you want to use to describe your workspace on this Linux machine.  (If your Perforce username is the same as your Linux login, and you're fine with using your local hostname as the client name, you can skip this.)

Then run:

```
p4 login
```

and enter your Perforce password (not your Linux password).

Then run:

```
p4 client
```

Make any edits you like to the client spec.  If you don't know what to do, just save it and exit the editor.  The default will do to get you started.

Then run:

```
p4 sync
```

This will sync files from the depot to your workspace, according to your client spec.  (If you just used the default client definition, everything in the depot is being synced to your current directory.)

https://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.051/manuals/p4guide/03_quickstart.html